# View all work-spaces associated with TFS

Tags: tfs, workspace

How to view all work-spaces associated with a specific Team Foundation Server?  I am using TFS 2012 , any command or any tool to show this info ?

Comment: Do you want to view local workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and you specify * for user, machine and workspace name